# Spring MVC 4 AJAX upload MultipartFile with extra parameters

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm currently developing a **file upload with AJAX** (jQuery) and **Spring MVC 4**. Besides the file itself I have to send some extra parameters, such as a description of the file being uploaded. I'm using an `$.ajax()` call that sends a `FormData` object along with my CSRF token, like described below:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("description", $('#description').val());
    formdata.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: '/upload',
    type: 'POST',
    headers : {"X-CSRF-TOKEN" : $('#myToken').val()}
    data: formdata,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Data Uploaded: "+data);
    }
});
```

I've found multiple examples of how to upload files using javascript's FormData object along with a Spring controller that receives a `MultipartFile` object, but when I try to retrieve the other parameters using `@RequestParam` I end up getting errors. Below is an example of what I was trying (**which didn't work**):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestParam(value = "description") String description) {

    //Do stuff...

}
```

After a lot of research and attempting different approaches, I found out that I could declare `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter and it would allow me to retrieve each parameter (but not the file itself). **Below is an working example**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, 
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    String description = request.getParameter("description");

    //Do some other stuff...

}
```

Even though the example above worked, the fact that I couldn't use annotations and have my parameters explicit in the method's signature was bugging me. So I tried a different approach changing the `@PRequestParam` annotation for a `@ModelAttribute` annotation, which surprisingly worked.

### My questions are:

1. **Why didn't `@RequestParam` worked, if the parameter was retrievable in the `HttpServletRequest` object?**
2. **Why did `@ModelAttribute` worked? Should I use it instead of retrieving things explicitly from `HttpServletRequest`?**

Answer (score 0):

this comes probably too late but you could pass the description as a parameter in the url:

```
url: '/upload?' + $.param({description: $('#description').val()});
```

don't forget the question mark!

and for the data you just pass the actual file:

```
data: $("#file")[0].files[0]
```

and your controller would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadFile(
    @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, 
    @RequestParam(value = "description") String description) {

//Do stuff...
```

}

hope that helps!